# Prove that $M_{n}(F)\otimes _{F}M_{m}(F)\simeq M_{nm}(F)$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> Suppose $F$ is a field. Then prove that $$M_{n}(F)\otimes _{F}M_{m}(F)\simeq M_{nm}(F)$$ as $F$-algebras.

I know that I should take $$\alpha :M_{n}(F)\otimes _{F}M_{m}(F)\rightarrow M_{nm}(F)$$ $$\alpha (A\otimes B)=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}B & ... &  &a_{1n}B \\ 
a_{21}B & ... &  & a_{2n}B\\ 
 &  &  & \\ 
a_{n1}B & ... &  & a_{nn}B
\end{bmatrix}$$ because it was the hint of the problem.

because $M_{n}(F)$ and $M_{m}(F)$ can be considered as $F$-Algebra (note that we can have $F\subseteq M_{m}(F)$ and $F\subseteq M_{n}(F)$ )so $M_{n}(F)\otimes _{F}M_{m}(F)\simeq M_{nm}(F)$ is a $F$-Algebra,with this multiplication $$(A\otimes B)({A}'\otimes {B}')=(A{A}')\otimes (B{B}')$$

I consider $$h :M_{n}(F)\times _{F}M_{m}(F)\rightarrow M_{nm}(F)$$ $$h (A, B)=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}B & ... &  &a_{1n}B \\ 
a_{21}B & ... &  & a_{2n}B\\ 
 &  &  & \\ 
a_{n1}B & ... &  & a_{nn}B
\end{bmatrix}$$ because $h$ is bilinear, by one theorem we have unique $F$-module homomorphism $\bar{h}$ that $$ \bar{h}:M_{n}(F)\otimes _{F}M_{m}(F)\rightarrow M_{nm}(F)$$ $$\bar{h}(A\otimes B)=h(A,B)$$
now I should show that $$\bar{h}((A\otimes B)({A}'\otimes {B}'))=\bar{h}(A\otimes B)\bar{h}({A}'\otimes {B}')$$ By using a lot of symbols for special case $n=m=2$ ,I show that it is right but I need a general way.so please help.

also I don't know how I should show that it is onto and one to one.
it is alot of symbols that make me confused.

Comment: For reference: this is called the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: Think about the basis of vector spaces $M_n(F)\otimes_F M_m(F)$ and $M_{nm}(F)$, then how to map one from another through $\bar{h}$. Counting dimensions over $F$ would suffice to prove the bijectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\def\End{\operatorname{End}}f\in\End(V)$ and $g\in\End(W)$ you can define
$$
\beta(f\otimes g)\colon V\otimes W\to V\otimes W
$$
by
$$
\beta(f\otimes g)(v\otimes w)=f(v)\otimes g(w)
$$
(check it's well defined). Therefore you have a (linear) map
$$
\beta\colon \End(V)\otimes \End(V)\to \End(V\otimes W)
$$
Assume now $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional.
If we can show $\beta$ is injective, then $\beta$ is also surjective, because of equality of dimensions.

If $\beta(f\otimes g)=0$, then $f(v)\otimes g(w)=0$, for all $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. If $f\ne 0$, then $f(v)\ne 0$ for some $v\in V$ and $f(v)$ can be completed to a basis of $V$; now $f(v)\otimes x=0$ implies $x=0$, because otherwise $x$ can be completed to a basis of $W$ and $f(v)\otimes x$ would belong to a basis of $V\otimes W$. Hence $g=0$, so $f\otimes g=0$. Therefore $\beta(f\otimes g)=0$ implies $f\otimes g=0$.

Now plug in two fixed bases of $V$ and $W$ to get your stated isomorphism.

Comment: I didn't understand,what is the relation between  $End(V)$ and $End(W)$ with matrix that is in the problem?

Comment: It will be great if you explain to me.thanks a lot.

Comment: The endomorphism ring of an $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space is isomorphic to $M_n(F)$ by just making a choice of a basis.